# Quote import from one org to another

Tags: queue

Can anyone tell me how can i import queues, case assignment rules and auto response rules from one salesforce org to another.

Answer (score 0):

You can export from source Org using difference tools like dataloader , excel connector etc.

Ex. Select Id, SobjectType, QueueId, Queue.Name From QueueSobject

Thanks